# Knex query en Node Js

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, knex

Amigos alguien podría decirme porque estoy recibiendo una promesa y no el puro objeto??

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
[ { name: 'kyo', lastname: 'ren' } ]
```

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  const queyk = knex().select('*').from('users');
  const users = [];
  queyk.then((data)=>{
  data.forEach((user) => {
    users.push (user); 
  });
  console.log(users);
  res.render('main', {users:users})
  });
  

});
```

Esto lo estoy obteniendo del este get, necesito meterlo en un objeto y pasarlo por handlebars, solo que handle no me encuentra **users**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código debería quedar de este modo

```
const visits = knex().select('*').from('users')

visits.then(function(data){
    data.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element["nombreColumna"])
    })
})
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

- Cuando haces uso de `select` debes indicar o el nombre de las columnas o el comodín `*` para traer todas las columnas
- La constante `visits` por separado la trabajas por medio de `then` para procesar a la *promise*
- El parámetro *data* que recibe la función dentro de la *promise* la recorres por dentro por medio de un *forEach* donde cada columna la vas a poder obtener por medio de el parámetro `element`
- Finalmente por medio de esta sintaxis accedes a cada columna por medio del nombre de cada una de ellas `element["nombreColumna"]`

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

En la consola de tu navegador deberías esta recibiendo algo **similar a esto**

```
$ node app.js
element1
element2
element3
element4
element5
element6
```

Comment: me da un knex.queryBuilder is not a function

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim probablemente por la versión, es decir tienes una diferente a la que uso; entonces pruebala como la acabo de dejar

Comment: Gracias súper like

Comment: oye como podría meter todos esos datos del foreach en un solo objeto? como const users = [] este?

Comment: Listo gracias por todo